# Data view items iterating horizontally

Tags: data-view-web-part

Has anyone gone through the process of using a data view to display items horizontally?

> Item1             
>     Item2             
>     Item3 
>     Metadata1    
>     Metadata2    
>     Metadata3 
>     Item4            
>     Item5            
>     Item6 
>     Metadata4    
>     Metadata5    
>     Metadata6

I'm looking to do this and set a condition to check for x items and create a new row.

Comment: I figured out how to get them to display horizontally, but don't know how to go about setting the conditional to create a new row.  My XSL isn't the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done, I'm currently doing it on something I'm working on. The key is to have a fixed width container for your items. Then for each item, it sits in a div with a fixed width and displayed inline-block. This will get you the automatic wrapping you want.

```
<div style="width: 900px;">
<div style="width: 280px; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;"><!--Repeat for each item --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense.  The route I was going was to smash all of the item info into each <td> and set an XSL variable to keep a count and start a new row based off that.  I like your way more, lets it be more dynamic..and less XSL.

Comment: Ya, since it's a DVWP, you have full control of the output, so spitting out your own markup works best here than trying to adapt to the default markup.

Comment: I did a very basic data view with this approach and seems to work very well.  Now just to format it correctly. Thanks!